# Google Analytics filter for only leaving certain parameters in URLs

Tags: google-analytics

I've got tons of parameters attached to my URLs which do not actually change the content on pages. I end up having the same page tracked as 100 different ones in Google Analytics.

Is there an efficient RegExp that would allow me to remove all parameters from my URLs when passed to GA apart from desired ones? (those that are actually used internally by GA: utm-parameters and GCLID value)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about Google analytics tracking and is not programing related may be better suited for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you know what parameters you want to remove, then you can use the query parameter removal feature in the view settings.